Initial migration recreates all tables despite scaffolding existing database
I have an existing database with a very old entity framework that generated it. I want to start fresh when it comes to classes however keep the old database (and it's data).
I have used ef power tools to scaffold the database but when I run initial migration I get a migration that wants to create tables which of cause is not possible since they already exists.
Do I need to do something special for the first migration in order for it to accept the initial tables/data. Or have I done something wrong when generating the first migration.
dotnet ef migrations add Initial --project .\MyProjectNameHere

Running .net 8 and latest Entity Framework.

Create this migration. And clear it's Up/Down method, Snapshot file should remain. Next migrations will be difference between shanpost file and your current model classes.
